# Compressing text for HTTP with POST parameters

Tags: http, post, compression

I am writing client software that initiates a HTTP request with a large blob of text (JSON object actually) as POST parameter. I want to compress this text before sending and decompress the text on the server.

Gzip produces binary, which I can't send as a POST parameter, I think.

Which options/algorithms exist to compress text and send it to a web server?

Edit: Would it be an option to GZIP and then BASE64 encode the binary data?

Comment: What language is the client-side application being written in?

Comment: Are you using the WebRequest Class or ?

Comment: Take a look at http://netomatix.com/HttpPostData.aspx - you simply need to compress the data prior to determining the length and transmitting it.

Comment: Most web servers only support serving compressed responses. I have not heard of server accepting a compressed request, neither would I know how to actually notify the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use the standard [HTTP gzip compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression)?

(It just seems a bit mad to needlessly re-invent the wheel.)

**Update**

Ah yes - my bad. So why not simply gzip the file, upload it to the server as you would a multipart/form-data file upload and then un-gzip it on the server?

Comment: I think HTTP gzip compresses data from the server to the client/browser. I need it the other way around, compress on the client and send to the server.

Comment: For some reason I assume that causes a lot of overhead because a file is written to the web servers file system, though that's just a hunch.

Comment: At some point the file has to end up on the server and de-compressing the data is a trivial overhead in this day and age.

Comment: Content-Encoding: gzip works both ways (at least it's supposed to).

Comment: @koen, @Julian Reschke: I know of no server that supports that. If you have a rich client, then you can do a manual compression and do the same on the server side handler.

Comment: @leppie: I recall using content-encoding: gzip for PUT and PROPPATCH years ago, at least in Tomcat and SAP J2EE, possibly in httpd and IIS as well.

Comment: @Julian Reschke: Definitely not supported in IIS. So how does the server advertise the 'accept-encoding' ?

Comment: @leppie: it doesn't, but that doesn't mean that it can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

The file is a long/unnecessary work around, the original question relates to battle with unbearably large Json blob. From my hacking around I can tell it highly depends on the server, some do support it some don't.

To the original question, you can set the binary data in http post, the real question what is the server going to do with it. It is the same way that C# client does not automatically unzip, you have to write extra code.