# Sending large svg data to server

Tags: java, svg, dojox.charting

In my application i have, charts i am using dojox charting for that.Now i want to export the charts as pdf. I have the following way to do it.

1. sending svg to server
2. rasterize svg,for which I am using apache batik.
3. Insert the rasterized image into pdf, for which I am using itext.

Now the issue is sending svg to server. At times the svg runs over more than 4000 characters.And the worst part is some times i have three to four charts at a time to export. So is there a way to send chart object to server and obtain svg? or what is the feasible way to send svg to server?

I also need the Chart Legend to be present in exporting pdf.
I am using Java for my server side.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You could compress the data before uploading it (svg compresses quite well), see e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427353/compressing-text-for-http-with-post-parameters.

Comment: The discussion in the e.g is confusing. Any way is this possible,sending chart object to server and obtain svg and Legend?